# Widget at the bottom of a ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

What I'd like to see on the screen is a list and below it a button, but the button should be right below the list and always visible, regardless of the list's size, and regardless of the list having a scrollbar because it's too large for the screen. The list should be at the top of the screen. What I currently have is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn"/>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If the list is large (so it needs more than the screen space it has) then it gets a scrollbar and everything is fine. What I don't like is what happens when the list is short: at the top of the screen there are a few list elements, and then at the bottom there's the button. If I switch the list's layout_height to wrap_content and adjust a few more parameters, then the button will be right below the list, as I wanted it. But with this layout, if the list is large, the button won't be visible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/list"
    android:text="button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So I wonder if there's a way to achieve this *"button near list"* just in XML. I tend to believe it's impossible, but I don't have a strong grasp of Android layouts. Going to Java, you can compute all sort of things and adjust the layout, but this seems error-prone, so what I will probably end up doing is put the button on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="48dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/list"
        android:text="button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that there is a fixed height of the button set as padding of the `ListView`. You should reference the same value from **dimen.xml** for both dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, this actually looks the way it was supposed to. The only improvement would be to get from somewhere the "48dp" rather than hard coding it, dimens.xml or not.

Comment: Yeah that's the drawback.. But if you want to have the layout defined with pure XML I don't see other way. Unless your button needs to be multi-line, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

as @assad's suggestion, have a linearlayout, and divide it into 10 parts. 1st part header, 2-9 parts for listview and last 10th part for button.

Comment: Thanks, but the button should always be visible, not be the last thing in the list.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/list"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The button is still at the bottom of the screen with a 4-element list rather than just below the 4th line

Comment: I have got your point now first calculate your listview size than set max hight of  your listview this will help you.   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren.htm @ciobi

Answer (score 0):

set the list to layout_alignParentTop AND layout_above button
and the button, set it to layout_alignParentBottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: this is good but listview items will shown beside the button because button is not below listview it is top of the listview. i Suggest Linear Layout

Answer (score 0):

Create a footer view layout consisting of your button, and add it

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
yourListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but the button should always on the screen, while addFooterView() puts it as the last element in the list. If the list is large, you can't see the button unless you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a footerView for this purpose Change your main xml to only contain listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now create another layout footer_button.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" >
</Button>
```

Now in your activity code

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    View b1 = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_button, null, false);
    lv.addFooterView(b1);
```

Caution: Add footer view before setting adapter to your listview

Comment: Yes, the button isn't hidden, but the list only has a line and a half shown, then the button underneath, then plenty of empty screen space.